# How do you confirm a scheduled event is working?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-event

Created an event using CREATE EVENT.

It exists:

```
 +---------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+------+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
 | Db      | Name                    | Definer        | Time zone | Type      | Execute at | Interval value | Interval field | Starts              | Ends | Status  | Originator | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
 +---------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+------+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
 | postfix | clean_spam_domains_TEST | root@localhost | SYSTEM    | RECURRING | NULL       | 5              | SECOND         | 2017-06-26 12:33:22 | NULL | ENABLED |          0 | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
 +---------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+------+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

To confirm it is working, I turned on logging:

```
 SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
 SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

So, I am expecting to see the execution of the event in the log once every 5 seconds.

I don't.

Should I? Or does this type of event not show in the `general_log`?

**Update**:
As requested, here is the output of `mysqladmin debug`:

```
Events status:
LLA = Last Locked At  LUA = Last Unlocked At
WOC = Waiting On Condition  DL = Data Locked

Event scheduler status:
State      : INITIALIZED
Thread id  : 0
LLA        : n/a:0
LUA        : n/a:0
WOC        : NO
Workers    : 0
Executed   : 0
Data locked: NO

Event queue status:
Element count   : 1
Data locked     : NO
Attempting lock : NO
LLA             : create_event:170
LUA             : create_event:174
WOC             : NO
Next activation : never
```

*Create statement*:

```
 CREATE EVENT clean_spam_domains_TEST
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
 delimiter $$
 DO BEGIN
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deathrow;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE deathrow (
 SELECT 
     whitelist_id
 FROM
     postfix.whitelist
         LEFT JOIN
     free_email_providers ON whitelist.whitelist_domain = free_email_providers.free_email_providers_domain
 WHERE
     free_email_providers_id IS NOT NULL);
 DELETE FROM whitelist 
 WHERE
     whitelist.whitelist_id IN (SELECT 
         whitelist_id
     FROM
         deathrow);
 END;
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Have you 1st confirmed whether the Event Scheduler [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-status-info.html) is running? Can you show us your CREATE EVENT statement? If running under Windows, "In addition, on Windows, the server by default writes events and error messages to the Windows Event Log within the Application log" [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html)

Comment: Updated. Also, running on Debian Jessie.

Comment: In the `SELECT`, simplify by removing `WHERE ...` and `LEFT`.  Further simplify by using multi-table `DELETE`, thereby avoiding tmp table and the slow `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Comment: Still no answer on this? I now have a second case where I need to confirm the schedules are firing correctly. In the second case, it should be running every 5 minutes, but appears that it hasn't run in two days.